# Replace System.Web.Helpers.Crypto in .net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, porting

I try to porting an asp.net mvc project to net.core
In past project I used the System.Web.Helpers.Crypto library to save hash passwords in my database.
In net.core there isn't  System.Web.Helpers, there is a porting of old library to use to create and compare hash password?

Comment: There is crypto support in .NET Core (see System.Security.Cryptography). It depends what you were using before. I believe Helpers.Crypto was doing PBKDF2 (aka RFC 2898), so I'd start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Just create your own Crypto type and copy source code from here:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/Crypto.cs

Comment: Thanks Andrey I did exactly that!